# Bug with wp_insert_term and switch_to_blog

Tags: wordpress

I'm running a network of about 80 sites using WP multisite 3.2. I'm experiencing irregularities using switch_to_blog whith wp_insert_term.

To test this I have disabled all plugins, and am testing on a blank page so nothing else interferes. This is the sample code:

```
switch_to_blog(75);
wp_insert_term( 'New Term','category');
restore_current_blog();
```

When run from *most blogs* it adds the new term to the desired blog and the permalink to the new term page works.

But for a few of the blogs, when it runs it adds the term, but the link to the new term page throws a 404 error. Opening wp-admin and adding any new term through wp-admin fixes it.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

If it runs in an other action (like save_post or simular) you might experience errors. So you can use `remove_action()` before and `add_action()` after you switch blog.
You "pause" and resume the action.

Comment: And if you try to add several categories. You cant insert an array with more then one category. You must use foreach an add them one after the other.